# Java: method to get position of a match in a String?

Tags: java, string, match

```
String match = "hello";
String text = "0123456789hello0123456789";

int position = getPosition(match, text); // should be 10, is there such a method?
```

Answer (score 281, accepted):

The family of methods that does this are:

- [`int indexOf(String str)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

  - [`indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int))
- [`int lastIndexOf(String str)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String))

  - [`lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,%20int))

> Returns the index within this string of the first (*or last*) occurrence of the specified substring [searching forward (*or backward*) starting at the specified index].

---

```
String text = "0123hello9012hello8901hello7890";
String word = "hello";

System.out.println(text.indexOf(word)); // prints "4"
System.out.println(text.lastIndexOf(word)); // prints "22"

// find all occurrences forward
for (int i = -1; (i = text.indexOf(word, i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
} // prints "4", "13", "22"

// find all occurrences backward
for (int i = text.length(); (i = text.lastIndexOf(word, i - 1)) != -1; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
} // prints "22", "13", "4"
```

Comment: lolz, just realised an assignment inside while-loop, then you post an assignment inside for-loop +1

Comment: @polygenelubricants - your "find all occurrences" examples are clever.  But if was code-reviewing that, you would get a lecture about code maintainability.

Comment: How would you write it? I'm honestly asking, because I haven't had a professional code review experience before.

Comment: In find all occurrences, instead of i++, we can write i += word.length(). It should be slightly faster.

Comment: First loop will fail to find all positions if matching one char. You don't need +1 in for loop second statement, because third statement does counting i++ try for String text = "0011100"; matching word char "1" it will print 2,4 not 2,3,4

Comment: @polygenelubricants Hi, this kind of for loop is interesting to me. I'd like to know more about why the variable i = -1, and how i++ seems to make it scan to the end of the text, can it be explained more? I'm not refuting it, I know it works, I just want to understand the logic

Comment: It's inclusive of `fromIndex` for anyone wondering.

Comment: Find all occurrences backward should be corrected as i--. not i++

Answer (score 50):

This works using regex.

```
String text = "I love you so much";
String wordToFind = "love";
Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
Matcher match = word.matcher(text);

while (match.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found love at index "+ match.start() +" - "+ (match.end()-1));
}
```

**Output :**

> Found 'love' at index 2 - 5

**General Rule :**

- Regex search left to right, and once the match characters has been used, it cannot be reused.

Comment: This works awesome, but for this sentence i got the output saying "I have a boyfriend" :-)

Answer (score 20):

```
text.indexOf(match);
```

See the [String javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 13):

## Finding a single index

As others have said, use `text.indexOf(match)` to find a single match.

```
String text = "0123456789hello0123456789";
String match = "hello";
int position = text.indexOf(match); // position = 10
```

## Finding multiple indexes

Because of [@StephenC's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615749/java-method-to-get-position-of-a-match-in-a-string/30204724#comment2627574_2615834) about code maintainability and my own difficulty in understanding [@polygenelubricants' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2615834/3681880), I wanted to find another way to get all the indexes of a match in a text string. The following code (which is modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034592/3681880)) does so:

```
String text = "0123hello9012hello8901hello7890";
String match = "hello";

int index = text.indexOf(match);
int matchLength = match.length();
while (index >= 0) {  // indexOf returns -1 if no match found
    System.out.println(index);
    index = text.indexOf(match, index + matchLength);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all matches in a file simply by assigning inside while-loop, cool:

```
$ javac MatchTest.java 
$ java MatchTest 
1
16
31
46
$ cat MatchTest.java 
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MatchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String match = "hello";
        String text = "hello0123456789hello0123456789hello1234567890hello3423243423232";
        int i =0;
        while((i=(text.indexOf(match,i)+1))>0)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you offset `i` by `+1` works, but in a rather roundabout way. As you've shown here, it reports the first `hello` at `i == 1`. It's much more consistent if you always use 0-based indexing.

Comment: ... will steal your thing :P Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
int match_position=text.indexOf(match);
```

Comment: Please explain what you did

Comment: @Fabio getPosition(match, text){
int match_position=text.indexOf(match); return match_position;}

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Occourence {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key=null,str ="my name noorus my name noorus";        
    int i=0,tot=0;

    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str," ");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {   
        tot=tot+1;
        key = st.nextToken();
        while((i=(str.indexOf(key,i)+1))>0)
        {
            System.out.println("position of "+key+" "+"is "+(i-1));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("total words present in string "+tot);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works and what's going on in the guard of the inner loop?  An explanation might be useful to a novice reader.

Comment: int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex): Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index. If it does not occur, -1 is returned.
Here the inner loop of while would be able to get all the occource of token(here specified by variable named as 'key').

Answer (score 1):

I have some big code but working nicely....

```
   class strDemo
   { 
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
       String s1=new String("The Ghost of The Arabean Sea");
           String s2=new String ("The");
           String s6=new String ("ehT");
           StringBuffer s3;
           StringBuffer s4=new StringBuffer(s1);
           StringBuffer s5=new StringBuffer(s2);
           char c1[]=new char[30];
           char c2[]=new char[5];
           char c3[]=new char[5];
           s1.getChars(0,28,c1,0);
           s2.getChars(0,3,c2,0);
           s6.getChars(0,3,c3,0); s3=s4.reverse();      
           int pf=0,pl=0;
           char c5[]=new char[30];
           s3.getChars(0,28,c5,0);
           for(int i=0;i<(s1.length()-s2.length());i++)
           {
               int j=0;
               if(pf<=1)
               {
                  while (c1[i+j]==c2[j] && j<=s2.length())
                  {           
                    j++;
                    System.out.println(s2.length()+" "+j);
                    if(j>=s2.length())
                    {
                       System.out.println("first match of(The) :->"+i);

                     }
                     pf=pf+1;         
                  }   
             }                
       }       
         for(int i=0;i<(s3.length()-s6.length()+1);i++)
        {
            int j=0;
            if(pl<=1)
            {
             while (c5[i+j]==c3[j] && j<=s6.length())
             {
                 j++;
                 System.out.println(s6.length()+" "+j);
                 if(j>=s6.length())
                 {
                         System.out.println((s3.length()-i-3));
                         pl=pl+1;

                 }   
                }                 
              }  
           }  
         }
       }
```

Comment: put some explaination/comment in your code will make people easier to understand your code especially it's long code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//finding a particular word any where inthe string and printing its index and occurence  
class IndOc
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s="this is hyderabad city and this is";
        System.out.println("the given string is ");
        System.out.println("----------"+s);
        char ch[]=s.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(" ----word is found at ");
        int j=0,noc=0;
        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
        {
            j=i;

            if(ch[i]=='i' && ch[j+1]=='s')
            {
                System.out.println(" index "+i);
            noc++;  
            }

        }
        System.out.println("----- no of occurences are "+noc);

    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String match = "hello";
    String text = "0123456789hello0123456789hello";

    int j = 0;
    String indxOfmatch = "";

    for (int i = -1; i < text.length()+1; i++) {
        j =  text.indexOf("hello", i);
        if (i>=j && j > -1) {
            indxOfmatch += text.indexOf("hello", i)+" ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(indxOfmatch);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a function which is very easy to understand for find word's location in a string, check it :-

```java
public static void indexOfWordByYash() {
    String str = "01yash898989yashyashyashgggggg";
    String find = "yash";
    int sizeOfFind = find.length();
    System.out.println("length of string ="+str.length());
    System.out.println("size of find ="+sizeOfFind);
        
    //In here we are checking if find_word available from index 0, becouse 
    //in loop we are not checking from 0 index.
    int index = str.indexOf("yash", 0);
    for(int loop=0; loop < str.length(); loop++) {
            
        //Only if index greater then 0 will print the index.
        if(index >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Index of yash ="+index);
            index = str.indexOf("yash", index+sizeOfFind);
        }
            
        //Break the loop if no any more find_word in string.
        if(index == -1) {
            System.out.println("index ="+index);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to scan for 'n' matches of the search string, I'd recommend using *[regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)*.
They have a steep learning curve, but they'll save you hours when it comes to complex searches.

Comment: Suggestion: Include an example of getting position from a regular expression. Just "try using regular expressions" is a rather basic comment and doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

for multiple occurrence and the character found in string??yes or no

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class SubStringtest {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     System.out.println("enter the string");
    String str=br.readLine();
    System.out.println("enter the character which you want");
    CharSequence ch=br.readLine();   
    boolean bool=str.contains(ch);
    System.out.println("the character found is " +bool);
    int position=str.indexOf(ch.toString());

    while(position>=0){
        System.out.println("the index no of character is " +position); 
        position=str.indexOf(ch.toString(),position+1);
    }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int NumberWordsInText(String FullText_, String WordToFind_, int[] positions_)
   {
    int iii1=0;
    int iii2=0;
    int iii3=0;
    while((iii1=(FullText_.indexOf(WordToFind_,iii1)+1))>0){iii2=iii2+1;}
    // iii2 is the number of the occurences
    if(iii2>0) {
        positions_ = new int[iii2];
        while ((iii1 = (FullText_.indexOf(WordToFind_, iii1) + 1)) > 0) {
            positions_[iii3] = iii1-1;
            iii3 = iii3 + 1;
            System.out.println("position=" + positions_[iii3 - 1]);
        }
    }
    return iii2;
}
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
     class Main{
     public static int string(String str, String str1){
     for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - str1.length(); i++){ 
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < str1.length(); j++) {
            if (str1.charAt(j) != str.charAt(i + j)) {
                break;
            }
            }
           if (j == str1.length()) {
           return i;
           }}
           return -1;
             }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the Substring");
    String str1=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The position of the Substring is "+string(str, str1));
    }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).