# Indexes of all occurrences of character in a string

Tags: java, loops, indexing, character

The following code will print 2

```
String word = "bannanas";
String guess = "n";
int index;
System.out.println( 
    index = word.indexOf(guess)
);
```

I would like to know how to get all the indexes of "n" ("guess") in the string "bannanas"

The expected result would be: `[2,3,5]`

Answer (score 198, accepted):

This should print the list of positions without the `-1` at the end that [Peter Lawrey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034468/535871) <strike>has</strike> had.

```
int index = word.indexOf(guess);
while (index >= 0) {
    System.out.println(index);
    index = word.indexOf(guess, index + 1);
}
```

It can also be done as a `for` loop:

```
for (int index = word.indexOf(guess);
     index >= 0;
     index = word.indexOf(guess, index + 1))
{
    System.out.println(index);
}
```

[Note: if `guess` can be longer than a single character, then it is possible, by analyzing the `guess` string, to loop through `word` faster than the above loops do. The benchmark for such an approach is the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm). However, the conditions that would favor using such an approach do not seem to be present.]

Answer (score 31):

Try the following (Which does not print -1 at the end now!)

```
int index = word.indexOf(guess);
while(index >= 0) {
   System.out.println(index);
   index = word.indexOf(guess, index+1);
}
```

Comment: you always print -1 at the end

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much for you answer, it seem to be right, but this is *actually* my first day with Java so I'm a little confused by the final result, this seems to output -1 at the end an I don't quite understand why! thanks!!

Comment: @Trufa: It always prints -1 at the end because `indexOf` returns -1 when the character is not found.

Comment: @Trufa - the reason it prints `-1` at the end is that the `do` loop executes the body and _then_ discovers that `index == -1` in the terminating `while`.

Comment: @ColinD that part I do get, what I don't understand is what is happen with the function for that to happen, it "loops" through the word looking for the occurrence of the character and until that is it can find no more right? and prints this last index of that is the not found (-1), is that what is happening? (I don't know if that came out right)

Comment: @Trufa: Yes, it always prints the index before checking whether it's -1.

Answer (score 14):

This can be done in a functional way with Java 9 using regular expression:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(guess)) // sanitize input and create pattern
            .matcher(word) // create matcher
            .results()     // get the MatchResults, Java 9 method
            .map(MatchResult::start) // get the first index
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // collect found indices into a list
    );
```

Here's the Kotlin Solution to add this logic as a new a new methods into `CharSequence` API using extension method:

```
 // Extension method
fun CharSequence.indicesOf(input: String): List<Int> =
    Regex(Pattern.quote(input)) // build regex
        .findAll(this)          // get the matches
        .map { it.range.first } // get the index
        .toCollection(mutableListOf()) // collect the result as list

// call the methods as
"Banana".indicesOf("a") // [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
String string = "bannanas";
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
char character = 'n';
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
    if(string.charAt(i) == character){
       list.add(i);
    }
}
```

Result would be used like this :

```
    for(Integer i : list){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Or as a array :

```
list.toArray();
```

Comment: op's guess variable is a string. Your solution only works for a character.

Answer (score 7):

With Java9, one can make use of the [`iterate(int seed, IntPredicate hasNext,IntUnaryOperator next)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) as follows:-

```
List<Integer> indexes = IntStream
          .iterate(word.indexOf(c), index -> index >= 0, index -> word.indexOf(c, index + 1))
          .boxed()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.printlnt(indexes);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int index = -1;
while((index = text.indexOf("on", index + 1)) >= 0) {
   LOG.d("index=" + index);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8+

To find all the indexes of a particular character in a `String`, one can create an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) of all the indexes and `filter` over it.

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
//...
String word = "bannanas";
char search = 'n';
//To get List of indexes:
List<Integer> indexes = IntStream.range(0, word.length())
        .filter(i -> word.charAt(i) == search).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
//To get array of indexes:
int[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, word.length())
        .filter(i -> word.charAt(i) == search).toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String word = "bannanas";

String guess = "n";

String temp = word;

while(temp.indexOf(guess) != -1) {
     int index = temp.indexOf(guess);
     System.out.println(index);
     temp = temp.substring(index + 1);
}
```

Comment: The general idea is right, but `word.substring(word)` won't compile. :P

Comment: Still has a problem : it prints continuously 2.

Comment: Gosh, i need to javac everything i post in here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a java 8 solution.

```
public int[] solution (String s, String subString){
        int initialIndex = s.indexOf(subString);
        List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (initialIndex >=0){
            indexList.add(initialIndex);
            initialIndex = s.indexOf(subString, initialIndex+1);
        }
        int [] intA = indexList.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
        return intA;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String input = "GATATATGCG";
    String substring = "G";
    String temp = input;
    String indexOF ="";
    int tempIntex=1;

    while(temp.indexOf(substring) != -1)
    {
        int index = temp.indexOf(substring);
        indexOF +=(index+tempIntex)+" ";
        tempIntex+=(index+1);
        temp = temp.substring(index + 1);
    }
    Log.e("indexOf ","" + indexOF);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if u want to find all indexes of a String in a String.

```
int index = word.indexOf(guess);
while (index >= 0) {
    System.out.println(index);
    index = word.indexOf(guess, index + guess.length());
}
```

Comment: This is interesting in that it raises an ambiguity in the meaning of "all occurrences". If `guess ` was `"aba"` and `word` was `"ababa"`, it's not clear if the `guess` occurs once or twice in `word`. (I mean, it's clear that one can find `guess` starting at two distinct positions, but since the occurrences overlap it's not clear whether they should both be counted.) This answer takes the view that overlapping occurrences are not counted as distinct. Of course, since OP's wording strongly suggests that `guess` will always have length 1, the ambiguity doesn't arise.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by iterating `myString` and shifting `fromIndex` parameter in `indexOf()`:

```
  int currentIndex = 0;

  while (
    myString.indexOf(
      mySubstring,
      currentIndex) >= 0) {

    System.out.println(currentIndex);

    currentIndex++;
  }
```

Comment: Did you even try running this code? It will print out every position (0, 1, 2, ...) until the index of the last occurrence of `mySubstring`, regardless of whether `mySubstring` can be found at each position. Not at all what OP wanted..

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, until I came up with this method.

```
public static int[] indexesOf(String s, String flag) {
    int flagLen = flag.length();
    String current = s;
    int[] res = new int[s.length()];
    int count = 0;
    int base = 0;
    while(current.contains(flag)) {
        int index = current.indexOf(flag);
        res[count] = index + base;
        base += index + flagLen;
        current = current.substring(current.indexOf(flag) + flagLen, current.length());
        ++ count;
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(res, count);
}
```

This method can be used to find indexes of any flag of any length in a string, for example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] indexes = indexesOf("Hello, yellow jello", "ll");

        // Prints [2, 9, 16]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexes));
    }

    public static int[] indexesOf(String s, String flag) {
        int flagLen = flag.length();
        String current = s;
        int[] res = new int[s.length()];
        int count = 0;
        int base = 0;
        while(current.contains(flag)) {
            int index = current.indexOf(flag);
            res[count] = index + base;
            base += index + flagLen;
            current = current.substring(current.indexOf(flag) + flagLen, current.length());
            ++ count;
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(res, count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A class for splitting strings I came up with. A short test is provided at the end.

`SplitStringUtils.smartSplitToShorterStrings(String str, int maxLen, int maxParts)` will split by spaces without breaking words, if possible, and if not, will split by indexes according to maxLen.

Other methods provided to control how it is split: `bruteSplitLimit(String str, int maxLen, int maxParts)`, `spaceSplit(String str, int maxLen, int maxParts)`.

```
public class SplitStringUtils {

  public static String[] smartSplitToShorterStrings(String str, int maxLen, int maxParts) {
    if (str.length() <= maxLen) {
      return new String[] {str};
    }
    if (str.length() > maxLen*maxParts) {
      return bruteSplitLimit(str, maxLen, maxParts);
    }

    String[] res = spaceSplit(str, maxLen, maxParts);
    if (res != null) {
      return res;
    }

    return bruteSplitLimit(str, maxLen, maxParts);
  }

  public static String[] bruteSplitLimit(String str, int maxLen, int maxParts) {
    String[] bruteArr = bruteSplit(str, maxLen);
    String[] ret = Arrays.stream(bruteArr)
          .limit(maxParts)
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
          .toArray(new String[maxParts]);
    return ret;
  }

  public static String[] bruteSplit(String name, int maxLen) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    int start =0;
    int end = maxLen;
    while (end <= name.length()) {
      String substr = name.substring(start, end);
      res.add(substr);
      start = end;
      end +=maxLen;
    }
    String substr = name.substring(start, name.length());
    res.add(substr);
    return res.toArray(new String[res.size()]);
  }

  public static String[] spaceSplit(String str, int maxLen, int maxParts) {
    List<Integer> spaceIndexes = findSplitPoints(str, ' ');
    List<Integer> goodSplitIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
    int goodIndex = -1; 
    int curPartMax = maxLen;
    for (int i=0; i< spaceIndexes.size(); i++) {
      int idx = spaceIndexes.get(i);
      if (idx < curPartMax) {
        goodIndex = idx;
      } else {
        goodSplitIndexes.add(goodIndex+1);
        curPartMax = goodIndex+1+maxLen;
      }
    }
    if (goodSplitIndexes.get(goodSplitIndexes.size()-1) != str.length()) {
      goodSplitIndexes.add(str.length());
    }
    if (goodSplitIndexes.size()<=maxParts) {
      List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
      int start = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<goodSplitIndexes.size(); i++) {
        int end = goodSplitIndexes.get(i);
        if (end-start > maxLen) {
          return null;
        }
        res.add(str.substring(start, end));
        start = end;
      }
      return res.toArray(new String[res.size()]);
    }
    return null;
  }


  private static List<Integer> findSplitPoints(String str, char c) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) == c) {
        list.add(i);
      }
    }
    list.add(str.length());
    return list;
  }
}
```

Simple test code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] testStrings = {
        "123",
        "123 123 123 1123 123 123 123 123 123 123",
        "123 54123 5123 513 54w567 3567 e56 73w45 63 567356 735687 4678 4678 u4678 u4678 56rt64w5 6546345",
        "1345678934576235784620957029356723578946",
        "12764444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444",
        "3463356 35673567567 3567 35 3567 35 675 653 673567 777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777"
    };

    int max = 35;
    int maxparts = 2;


    for (String str : testStrings) {
      System.out.println("TEST\n    |"+str+"|");
      printSplitDetails(max, maxparts);
      String[] res = smartSplitToShorterStrings(str, max, maxparts);
      for (int i=0; i< res.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("  "+i+": "+res[i]);
      }
      System.out.println("===========================================================================================================================================================");
    }

  }

  static void printSplitDetails(int max, int maxparts) {
    System.out.print("  X: ");
    for (int i=0; i<max*maxparts; i++) {
      if (i%max == 0) {
        System.out.print("|");
      } else {
        System.out.print("-");
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Pavneet_Singh's answer, a kotlin extension function to return a pair of start and end of the substring, and ignore cases.

```
fun CharSequence.indicesOf(input: String): List<Pair<Int, Int>> =
Pattern.compile(input, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).toRegex()
    .findAll(this)
    .map { Pair(it.range.first, it.range.last) }
    .toCollection(mutableListOf())
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this

```
String str = "helloslkhellodjladfjhello";
String findStr = "hello";

System.out.println(StringUtils.countMatches(str, findStr));
```

Comment: This is good for counting instances of a substring in a larger string, but does not return the indices of the matches.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The question require a list of all indices

Comment: This does not answers question & moreover, There are multiple providers for StringUtils. Which library is used is ambiguous.