# Geting Index Of set of Item values using Java

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

Is it possible to  get the index of a set of values in a document using Java just as you can do with `indexOf()` in array? I have tried to look it up in the Notes help but could not find and helpful tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a Vector of your item's values with `getValues()` and then you can use `indexOf()`:

```
Item item = doc.getFirstItem(itemName);
int index = item.getValues().indexOf("yourValue")
```

As an alternative, you can use Document's `getItemValue()` to get the Vector of your item's values:

```
int index = doc.getItemValue(itemName).indexOf("yourValue")
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to take the text from the document and to parse it. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034442/indexes-of-all-occurrences-of-character-in-a-string).

Comment: indexOf() did not work with NotesItem i have tried that

Comment: A solution is to put the document text into a data structure (like String), and after that you can parse easily.

Answer (score 0):

After this line of code...

```
Vector v = session.evaluate("@Member(\"value\";\"itemName\")");
```

`v.firstElement()` will contain the index of the value you are searching for, but it is one-based instead of zero-based. I.e., if the first value in the item matches the value you are looking for, the return is 1, not the 0 that would expect for indexOf() with a Java ArrayList.

*Note: the fact that evaluate() returns a Vector seems odd in this context, but most Notes formula language constructs can return either a single value or a list, depending on values in the document, so it always returns a vector even when the formula really only returns one value.*