# Reading ascii file line by line - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, ascii

I am trying to read an ascii file and recognize the position of newline character "\n" as to know which and how many characters i have in every line.The file size is 538MB. When i run the below code it never prints me anything.
I search a lot but i didn't find anything for ascii files. I use netbeans and Java 8. Any ideas??

Below is my code.

```
String inputFile = "C:\myfile.txt";
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
FileChannel ch = in.getChannel();
int BUFSIZE = 512;
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFSIZE);
Charset cs = Charset.forName("ASCII");

while ( (rd = ch.read( buf )) != -1 ) {
        buf.rewind();
        CharBuffer chbuf = cs.decode(buf);

        for ( int i = 0; i < chbuf.length(); i++ ) {
             if (chbuf.get() == '\n'){
                System.out.println("PRINT SOMETHING");
             }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file-in-java ?

Comment: I have already seen this post but with BufferReader it throws me Java Out of Memory error so i am not able to use the readline() function.

Comment: Use `RandomAccessFile` instead of `FileReaders` for large files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of characters in a line is the length of the string read by a `readLine` call:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    int iLine = 0;
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println( "Line " + iLine + " has " +
                            line.length() + " characters." );
        iLine++;
    }
} catch( IOException ioe ){
    // ...
}
```

Note that the (system-dependent) line end marker has been stripped from the string by `readLine`.

If a very large file contains no newlines, it is indeed possible to run out of memory. Reading character by character will avoid this.

```
    File file = new File( "Z.java" );
    Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
    int len = 0;
    int c;
    int iLine = 0;
    while( (c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        if( c == '\n' ){
            iLine++;
            System.out.println( "line " + iLine + " contains " +
                                len + " characters" );
            len = 0;
         } else {
            len++;
         }
    }
    reader.close();
```

Comment: With BufferedReader it throws me java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. Thats why i use ByteBuffer.

Comment: @Iostromos Is it possible that the entire file doesn't contain line ends? Is this a "regular" text file or some weird bunch of bytes?

Comment: @Iostromos Added a version not storing any file data - this should be OK. (If too slow: it can be improved.)

Comment: It really throws me OOM, what kind of verifyable example you want to post? Thats a link from the screenshot i just capture with the error message [link](http://prntscr.com/8v6vqn)

Comment: The file contains newline characters, and its an array 65x65 with 0 and 1 as elements but in an ascii format.

Comment: I try the new version of your code. The code runs without errors but program ends without entering the if condition. Any other ideas?

Comment: If I run the 2nd version with its own .java file as input it enters the then branch correctly for each line. - A 65x65 array of 0 and 1 isn't 538MB. And how do you know it contains newline characters? - Can you post a data file where you think the 2nd version doesn't find line lengths correctly?

Comment: I didnt understand the file correctly, but now i did. It not an 65x65 array, my mistake. It has 65columns and 1000+ rows with 0 and 1 as elements. Also as comment for your above code, as i mention its an ascii file, so in your code in c value got the ascii codes of 0 1 and space (48, 49 and 32 accordingly). I have to decode the read values first as to get the 0 and 1 and not the ascii codes of them.

Comment: So you don't need to know the number of characters in a line - you have to decode the characters and store the (numeric or bit) values 0 and 1 in a suitable data structure. - It's not the reading of the lines that is causing the OOM - you create your problems with the data structure, I bet. You should show all of your code, not jsut a part and claim that this causes OOM.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't confusing something? 1000 lines containing 65 zeroes and ones have a size of less than 130K. To reach 538MB you need - well, you can do the math.

Comment: You were right about the size of the array. Its an 1680x1680 array. And i found the solution. Your code is correct in a way. As to find the position of the newline character i just write an if statement for c to be equal to 92 (ascii code for "\")(or equal to 110 ascii code for "n"). As for the OOM the second code you posted doesnt throw error as i said before. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, so mark the answer as accepted - and don't test for "\" - this isn't in the ASCII file, and neither is "n"!

Answer (score 1):

Method to store the contents of a file to a string:

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException 
{
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

Here's a way to find the occurrences of a character in the entire string:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String content = readFile("filetest", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int index = content.indexOf('\n');
    while (index >= 0)
    {
        indexes.add(index);
        index = content.indexOf('\n', index + 1);
    }
}
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034442/indexes-of-all-occurrences-of-character-in-a-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file).

Comment: This method also throws out of memory error. I mentioned to a large file up to 538MB.

Answer (score 0):

You should user [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) which is convenience class for reading character files.

[FileInputStream javs docs clearly states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

> FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as
>   image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using
>   FileReader.

Try below

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       for (int pos = line.indexOf("\n"); pos != -1; pos = line.indexOf("\n", pos + 1)) {
        System.out.println("\\n at " + pos);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It stops running due to Compilation error. How to ignore it??

Comment: It would be surprising if this snippet would print anything.

Comment: @laune I have corrected one minor error. Let me know if you still think  it won't work ?

Comment: It throws a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error.