# Substring: get index of "or" occurrence in string

Tags: java, android

How can I `substring` the third number in the `String` below:

```
String val = "2020202030 or 303030303 or 303033303";
```

For two numbers the solution is as follows:

```
String val = "2020202030 or 303030303

firstNumber = val.substring(0,val.indexOf("or")-1);
secondNumber = val.substring(val.indexOf("or") + 3,val.length());
```

But how can I get the index of the second "or" in the `String` below?

```
String val = "2020202030 or 303030303 or 303033303";

firstNumber = val.substring(0,val.indexOf("or")-1);
secondNumber = val.substring(val.indexOf("or")-1,<index of second or >?);
thirdNumber= val.substring(<index of second or>?,val.length());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use split :

```
String[] numbers = val.split(" or ");
```

`numbers[2]` will contain the 3rd number.

If you prefer to use `indexOf` to get the index of the 2nd "or", use the `int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` variant.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034592/2668213

Then elaborate it just a bit. For example

```
int n_occurrences = 0

for (int index = val.indexOf("or");
     index >= 0;
     index = val.indexOf("or", index + 1))
{
    n_occurrences++;
    if (n_occurrences=2) 
       System.out.println(index);
}
```

Comment: Eran's answer is way better. Use that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String val = "2020202030 or 303030303 or 303033303";

String[] arr = val.split(" or ");

System.out.println(arr[0]); //2020202030

System.out.println(arr[1]); //303030303

System.out.println(arr[2]); //303033303
```

Comment: Care to explain why it answers the question ?

Comment: Above I have used split function of java which returns the array, so when we split the above string with " or " we get the above string in array format with first element as "2020202030" and so on