# Get index of 3rd comma

Tags: java

For example I have this string params: `Blabla,1,Yooooooo,Stackoverflow,foo,chinese`

And I want to get the string `testCaseParams` until the 3rd comma: `Blabla,1,Yooooooo`

and then remove it and the comma from the original string so I get this`Stackoverflow,foo,chinese`

I'm trying this code but `testCaseParams` only shows the first two values (gets index of the 2nd comma, not 3rd...)

```
 //Get how many parameters this test case has and group the parameters
        int amountOfInputs = 3;
        int index = params.indexOf(',', params.indexOf(',') + amountOfInputs);
        String testCaseParams = params.substring(0,index);
        params = params.replace(testCaseParams + ",","");
```

Comment: use String split(","), and iterate over the elements you want (starting from index 3

Comment: This is an coding challenge. Should write the code, not use Java.

Comment: @HuyVo "Should write the code, not use Java"... So, he should write the code, without coding? how do you see that happening?

Comment: @HuyVo no, I don't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034442/indexes-of-all-occurrences-of-character-in-a-string Did you looked at this post? I think it will help you.

Comment: @LeonardPera only if your goal is to make it needlessly difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold the index of the currently-found comma in a variable and iterate until the third comma is found:

```
int index = 0;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) index = str.indexOf(',', index);
String left = str.substring(0, index);
String right = str.substring(index+1);  // skip comma
```

Edit: to validate the string, simply check if `index == -1`. If so, there are not 3 commas in the string.

Comment: The last param string doesnt have a comma in the end.

Comment: @fsdf Do you mean `left` _shouldn't_ have a comma in the end?

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: @fsdf That means that your string does not have three occurrences of `,`. You can add input validation before this code.

Comment: DUDE It'S THE LAST GROUP IT DOESNT HAVE THE COMMA AND IT'S SUPPOSED TO BE LIKE THAT!!!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be a clever use of [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
String input = "Blabla,1,Yooooooo,Stackoverflow,foo,chinese";
String[] parts = input.split("(?=,)");
String output = parts[0] + parts[1] + parts[2];
System.out.println(output);
```

### Demo

Comment: why not just replace the int index line with an iteration creating the required String?

Answer (score 0):

One can use split with a limit of 4.

```
String input = "Blabla,1,Yooooooo,Stackoverflow,foo,chinese";
String[] parts = input.split(",", 4);
if (parts.length == 4) {
    String first = parts[0] + "," + parts[1] + "," + parts[2];
    String second = parts[3]; // "Stackoverflow,foo,chinese"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split with this regex to get the 2 pats:

```
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\G.*,.*,.*),");
```

It will result in `parts` equal to:

```
{ "Blabla,1,Yooooooo", "Stackoverflow,foo,chinese" }
```

`\\G` refers to the previous match or the start of the string.
`(?<=)` is [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind).

So it means match a comma for splitting, if it is preceded by 2 other commas since the previous match or the start of the string.

This will keep empty strings between commas.

Answer (score 0):

I offer this here just as a "fun" one line solution:

```
public static int nthIndexOf(String str, String c, int n) {
    return str.length() - str.replace(c, "").length() < n ? -1 : n == 1 ? str.indexOf(c) : c.length() + str.indexOf(c) + nthIndexOf(str.substring(str.indexOf(c) + c.length()), c, n - 1);
}

//Usage
System.out.println(nthIndexOf("Blabla,1,Yooooooo,Stackoverflow,foo,chinese", ",", 3)); //17
```

(It's recursive of course, so will blow up on large strings, it's relatively slow, and certainly *isn't* a sensible way to do this in production.)

As a more sensbile one liner using a library, you can use Apache commons [ordinalIndexOf()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29), which achieves the same thing in a more sensible way!