# Comparing the value of a char class variable with a string class variable

Tags: java

I am trying to compare a user entered character(letter) with individual letters in a word; and generating an appropriate message when this letter matches any of these individual letters in the word.
As I ask the user to enter the letter like:

```
String newLetter;
Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your letter: ");
newLetter = keyboard.next();
```

It assumes that the entered letter is a string(I can not express is otherwise, for example with char)
on the other hand, I express individual letters of a given word as:

```
char i=word.charAt(n-1);
```

where n equals the length of the string(word).
But, when I tend to compare i with newLetter, to see if these letters are the same or not, I cannot find any solution; however, both of them return a letter but one of them was defined as 'string' and the other one as 'char'.
Can you please assist me with that and if there is anything wrong here? Thanks a lot

Comment: which character of string you want to compare?

Comment: The question is that for example: you are given a word like " Programming" and you are trying to find out if a user's input letter (for example: 'a') can be found in that word and if yes, at which index(s).

Comment: You van use `a.indexOf(b);` it will return the index of the character found in String a. If its not in string a it will return -1

Comment: Thanks.How may I print the indexes if that letter was found at several indexes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034442/indexes-of-all-occurrences-of-character-in-a-string