# Kotlin save indexes of a specific char repeating in a string

Tags: android, arrays, string, kotlin

String example (not necessary A and B, but not X): AAAXBBXBXBBB
I want to find all occoruncaes of X and save them in an array.

I wrote a function:

```
val arrayList = ArrayList<Int>()
fun findAllX(str: String){
    for(i in 0 until str.length){
        if(str[i] == 'X'){
            arrayList.add(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Result in this example: arrayList that contains integers 3, 6, 8

Is there a better/cleaner way to write this?

Comment: `AAAXBBXBXBBB` this is the string, right? And now you want to get `X` from this string?

Comment: I wanted indexes (positions), like: 3, 6, 8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034442/indexes-of-all-occurrences-of-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner:

```kotlin
"AAAXBBXBXBBB".withIndex().filter { it.value == 'X' }.map { it.index }.toTypedArray()
```