# Method to get position of match in String within a range

Tags: java, string

My question is very similar to this one

[Java: method to get position of a match in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615749/java-method-to-get-position-of-a-match-in-a-string)

Except that I will be searching through very long strings (hundreds of megabytes) so I would like for the method to give up after a certain index.

Something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) except with an end index as well.  Is there a library that provides this functionality?

Comment: You can do a `substring(0, endIndex)` and then call the `indexOf(match)` on the resulted string or just read how many bytes you need and then try matching.

Comment: The following is **not** a duplicate. Hopefully it will give you additional ideas.  [Fast alernative for String#indexOf(String str)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564610/fast-alernative-for-stringindexofstring-str)

Answer (score 0):

Ye you can co this in 2 steps.

1. Get the Substring in which you want to search i.e. from beginning to the endIndex(or Certain index) using `subString(0, certainIndex)`
2. Then use `indexOf(matchString)` to find the location i=of the first occurence of the pattern into the String.