# Login with File Input/ android

Tags: android, authentication

I am a beginner in android development and i couldn't find out which logic should i apply. 
I want to perform a login with File Input/Output in java, 
Now i am able to write text to file, text is "username is admin password is admin"
Now when i want to read from this file, i want to apply some login that if the username written in file is "admin" and password written in file is "admin"
then show toast, else error.
I am not able to figure out that how to read keyword "admin" from this text file.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

1. Create object of sharedPreferences

   `sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
2. Store login details

   `private void setLoginDetails(String userName, String password) {
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
           editor.putString("userName",userName);
           editor.putString("password",password);
           editor.commit();
       }`
3. To check login

   `private boolean isValidUser(String userName, String password) {
           if(sharedPreferences.getString("userName",null).equals(userName) && sharedPreferences.getString("password",null).equals(password))
               return true;
           else
               return false;
       }`

**

> Don't save password in sharedPreferences.

** If you really want Its best practice to Encrypt data and save in sharedPreferences. To validate get data from sharedPreferences and Decrypt it.

Comment: Problem is solved sir, All i wanted was to extract value of username and password from the saved data. i used String.split() method and stored the values in an array and then compared those values with the values from the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

you can use android shared preference or database if you save a file in android sdcard any one can see this file and can modify it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not done your research. I have just TYPED **"how to read from a file in android"** in Google and got the answer in **FIRST** link. You must do research before asking question here.

By using **StringBuilder** and **BufferedReader** you can get all TEXT written in file. Store it in String type variable.
Than, You can **EASILY** find start, last index of searching word from that String type variable by using `indexOf(searching word)` and `lastIndexOf(searching word)`.

You can get reference of that methods [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615749/java-method-to-get-position-of-a-match-in-a-string).

By the way below link has your answer. Just check it out.

[Read from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and the  link Maulik but i had knowledge that how to read data from a file in android, all i wanted to know that how could i extract that specific values of username and password.

Comment: In that file the **ONLY** text is "username is admin password is admin". Am I right?@user3588320

Comment: Yeah the only text that was stored was 
"username is admin password is admin"
So i used string.split method and splited the string and stored it into array and then in the textview i saved the value at specified index of that array.

Comment: Okay. Can you post your answer or you can ACCEPT any answer which has been posted here and you have used.@user3588320

Answer (score 0):

the only text that was stored was "username is admin password is admin" So i used string.split method and splited the string and stored it into array and then in the textview i saved the value at specified index of that array