# Java:How do I make the "char" parameter into a String parameter in this specific java method?

Tags: java

```
public static int getNthOccurrence(int n, char find, String str)
    {
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i)==find)
            {
                counter++;
                if(counter==n)
                    return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

I have already seen this thread [Java: method to get position of a match in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615749/java-method-to-get-position-of-a-match-in-a-string)

The code runs that:

```
int n=getNthOccurrence(3,'n',"you arent gonna find me");
```

> output: 13

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What are you looking for it to do?

Comment: Are you asking how to replace `find` with a single character `String` or with a general `String`?

Comment: @Eran general String

Comment: Swapping the word "char" with "String"? What isn't working? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @DavyM I have tried that, but how would I change the line (str.charAt(i)==find) so that it works with Strings?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've changed the parameter type to `String`:

```
public static int getNthOccurrence(int n, String find, String str)
```

Use [`String.indexOf(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-):

```
i = -find.length();
for (int count = 0; count < n; ++count) {
  i = str.indexOf(find, i + find.length());
  if (i < 0) break;
}
return (i >= 0) ? i : -1;
```

(Note that `String.indexOf(char, int)` is a preferable way to do it with `char`, as in the case of the original code).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a char into a String by simply doing this

```
String theString = yourChar + "";
```

Your code could look something like this **!spoiler below!**

```
public static int getNthOccurrence(int n, char find, String str)
    {

        String f = find + "";
        int counter = 0;

        for (String c : str.split("")){

            if (c.equals(f)) n--;
            if (n < 1 ) return counter;
            counter++;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is quite what OP meant, because this offers no advantage over the current way. Moreover, this is just a poor approach: don't split `str`, just iterate over the indices and use `str.regionMatches(i, f, 0, f.length())`.

Comment: What makes the approach poor?

Comment: Splitting the string to iterate it character-by-character.

Comment: Yes, why is that poor?

Comment: Because you can iterate it character-by-character using `str.charAt`. Converting everything to a string requires you to create a string per character, as well as an array to hold the strings; but it's unnecessary because the only operation you do (equals, on a string that is always 1 char long) can be done equivalently with chars.