# Is there a way to find a word by searching for only part of it?

Tags: java

I need to take a phrase that contains a specific word, then if it does have that word even if it's part of another word, to print the entire word out.

I think how to find the word `"apple"`, but I can't figure how to find the word `"appletree"`.

So far, I have some code that finds the word apple and prints that out.

```
String phrase = "She's sitting under an appletree!"; 

if (phrase.contains("apple")) {
    System.out.println("apple");
} else { 
    System.out.println("none"); 
}
```

How do I print `"appletree"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: method to get position of a match in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615749/java-method-to-get-position-of-a-match-in-a-string)

Comment: If the phrase be coincident with the entire string, then you may use `if (phrase.contains("apple"))`

Comment: I would do this by splitting the string into words, then looping through each **word** to check whether it contains "apple", instead of the whole phrase. As soon as a word contains apple, you can print the word and exit your loop. Try googling how to split a string by whitespace if you aren't sure how to split a string into words.

Comment: @StephenC  I think I meant a string. And then to find out the rest of the phrase after the chose word. In which case I should have put a space between apple and tree, so it's two words. "She's sitting under an apple tree!" So how would I capture from apple all the way to ! ?

Answer (score 2):

Use regex for a 1-liner:

```
String target = phrase.replaceAll(".*?(\\w*apple\\w*).*", "$1");
```

This works by matching (and thus replacing) the entire input, but capturing the target then using a backreference (`$1`) to the captured input resulting in just the target being returned.

The word in which `apple` appears is matched using `\\w*` (ie any number of word chars) at either end of `apple`. The minimum number of leading chars are matched outside the target by using a *reluctant* quantifier `.*?`, otherwise that expression would match all the way to `apple`, which would miss words like `dapple`.

---

Test code:

```
String phrase = "She's sitting under an appletree!";
String target = phrase.replaceAll(".*?(\\w*apple\\w*).*", "$1");
System.out.println(target);
```

Output:

```
appletree
```

Answer (score 0):

You could import a scanner to read the phrase. You would use the scanner.next() to capture each token of input into a String variable "s", in this case each word, and then use the if statement if(s.contains("apple")) then System.out.println(s).

Hope this helps!

- Robin.

Answer (score 0):

without using regex you could simply split the sentence into words, loop through and check if it contains the requested word - old school style

```
String [] arr = phrase.split ("\\s+");
for (String word : arr) {
    if (word.contains("apple")) return word;
}
```